# Json Android RecyclerView Volley или Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Имеется такого вида json

```
{"results":{"opensearch:Query":{"#text":"","role":"request","startPage":"1"},"opensearch:totalResults":"641061","opensearch:startIndex":"0","opensearch:itemsPerPage":"30","trackmatches":{"track":[{"name":"Believer","artist":"Imagine Dragons","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Imagine+Dragons/_/Believer","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"212941","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/cc4a0ca262a3f10f44051a331f43d491.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/cc4a0ca262a3f10f44051a331f43d491.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/cc4a0ca262a3f10f44051a331f43d491.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/cc4a0ca262a3f10f44051a331f43d491.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":""},{"name":"Believe Me Natalie","artist":"The Killers","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Killers/_/Believe+Me+Natalie","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"611121","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"a2ba2c25-6d84-4b87-8153-c5a3dd160589"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"Cher","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Cher/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"427403","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/b94a02b10c0768911a9bd054363c44f1.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/b94a02b10c0768911a9bd054363c44f1.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/b94a02b10c0768911a9bd054363c44f1.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/b94a02b10c0768911a9bd054363c44f1.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"32ca187e-ee25-4f18-b7d0-3b6713f24635"},{"name":"I Believe in a Thing Called Love","artist":"The Darkness","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Darkness/_/I+Believe+in+a+Thing+Called+Love","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"525093","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/0357a625be1346fc9cbc2ae68ef70198.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/0357a625be1346fc9cbc2ae68ef70198.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/0357a625be1346fc9cbc2ae68ef70198.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/0357a625be1346fc9cbc2ae68ef70198.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"2afe5070-b737-4b24-85d2-ea4cafbfbbaa"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"Mumford & Sons","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Mumford+&+Sons/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"238495","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/32419a63e66e4b929ab9d4997a7b6ecb.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/32419a63e66e4b929ab9d4997a7b6ecb.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/32419a63e66e4b929ab9d4997a7b6ecb.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/32419a63e66e4b929ab9d4997a7b6ecb.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":""},{"name":"Believe","artist":"The Bravery","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Bravery/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"317334","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/bf8f55abd545e56e68daee307bb39cf0.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/bf8f55abd545e56e68daee307bb39cf0.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/bf8f55abd545e56e68daee307bb39cf0.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/bf8f55abd545e56e68daee307bb39cf0.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"f094670a-2b0d-41ef-a549-10ab41b6c4a1"},{"name":"Okay I Believe You, But My Tommy Gun Don't","artist":"Brand New","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Brand+New/_/Okay+I+Believe+You,+But+My+Tommy+Gun+Don%27t","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"276519","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/f2025cd60cef444386702df47589d6ba.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/f2025cd60cef444386702df47589d6ba.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/f2025cd60cef444386702df47589d6ba.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/f2025cd60cef444386702df47589d6ba.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":""},{"name":"I Believe","artist":"Simian Mobile Disco","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Simian+Mobile+Disco/_/I+Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"285693","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/a61c69898de34f29bd04d3fc74039809.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/a61c69898de34f29bd04d3fc74039809.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/a61c69898de34f29bd04d3fc74039809.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/a61c69898de34f29bd04d3fc74039809.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"7a1837e6-d7ee-4b51-8be4-4e70d84793b3"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"Disturbed","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Disturbed/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"210970","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/466f9b6181c54cd58056d906c9185971.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/466f9b6181c54cd58056d906c9185971.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/466f9b6181c54cd58056d906c9185971.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/466f9b6181c54cd58056d906c9185971.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"26707c4f-a050-41c0-a8fd-151dd22e3a1b"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"Yellowcard","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Yellowcard/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"189111","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/55a8d78f0e8248d3bd5b2e2db3e606ba.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/55a8d78f0e8248d3bd5b2e2db3e606ba.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/55a8d78f0e8248d3bd5b2e2db3e606ba.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/55a8d78f0e8248d3bd5b2e2db3e606ba.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"ba2da86c-cde1-4b89-b020-0c8c580bea1a"},{"name":"We Believe","artist":"Red Hot Chili Peppers","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers/_/We+Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"309066","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/ff9c5cb557a7489f8ef032b993638d18.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/ff9c5cb557a7489f8ef032b993638d18.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/ff9c5cb557a7489f8ef032b993638d18.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/ff9c5cb557a7489f8ef032b993638d18.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"5750327d-09ba-43e5-bd75-a08ba29e22f5"},{"name":"I'll Believe in Anything","artist":"Wolf Parade","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Wolf+Parade/_/I%27ll+Believe+in+Anything","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"257609","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/57b8ebcc55fc48ba8a1d0fcd3629d684.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/57b8ebcc55fc48ba8a1d0fcd3629d684.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/57b8ebcc55fc48ba8a1d0fcd3629d684.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/57b8ebcc55fc48ba8a1d0fcd3629d684.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"27dba9c5-27de-4c07-a7bd-f279cacc34d5"},{"name":"Believe Me","artist":"Fort Minor","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Fort+Minor/_/Believe+Me","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"154909","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/c276364fe696645982819e8c587f9510.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/c276364fe696645982819e8c587f9510.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/c276364fe696645982819e8c587f9510.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/c276364fe696645982819e8c587f9510.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":""},{"name":"Daydream Believer","artist":"The Monkees","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Monkees/_/Daydream+Believer","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"268221","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"87a239cc-9e5a-4377-8c43-ab879b876d8f"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"The Chemical Brothers","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Chemical+Brothers/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"206454","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/e1e95455e01844e2869b7c68d669d3ff.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/e1e95455e01844e2869b7c68d669d3ff.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/e1e95455e01844e2869b7c68d669d3ff.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/e1e95455e01844e2869b7c68d669d3ff.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"78f7eeb7-b38c-445d-955e-aed0daf98161"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"Breaking Benjamin","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Breaking+Benjamin/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"156681","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/3c33b2f17cfc6f2723b9e6d8aa810a43.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/3c33b2f17cfc6f2723b9e6d8aa810a43.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/3c33b2f17cfc6f2723b9e6d8aa810a43.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/3c33b2f17cfc6f2723b9e6d8aa810a43.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"f3cf4bb7-5869-4196-9a42-6c426022fbce"},{"name":"I Believe I Can Fly","artist":"R. Kelly","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/R.+Kelly/_/I+Believe+I+Can+Fly","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"278679","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/69b47e6dc7d04208924f07c430548880.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/69b47e6dc7d04208924f07c430548880.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/69b47e6dc7d04208924f07c430548880.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/69b47e6dc7d04208924f07c430548880.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"911d8cf2-376a-42ea-a91a-8b20d3c668c2"},{"name":"I Believe in Your Victory","artist":"This Will Destroy You","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/This+Will+Destroy+You/_/I+Believe+in+Your+Victory","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"161620","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/3a2c15dd1219418aa946d4755a61c30a.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/3a2c15dd1219418aa946d4755a61c30a.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/3a2c15dd1219418aa946d4755a61c30a.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/3a2c15dd1219418aa946d4755a61c30a.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"1c07f8d6-db4a-4666-8852-4ff80511fa92"},{"name":"We Believe","artist":"Good Charlotte","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Good+Charlotte/_/We+Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"215268","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/1caba0e1f32043fda330e2eed0e2c049.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/1caba0e1f32043fda330e2eed0e2c049.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/1caba0e1f32043fda330e2eed0e2c049.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1caba0e1f32043fda330e2eed0e2c049.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"80951a1c-aa14-4340-950b-9d9d0729276a"},{"name":"I'm a Believer","artist":"The Monkees","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Monkees/_/I%27m+a+Believer","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"409772","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/c6f23d8ab1c2499cb0d8202e18061673.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"29701c94-70d1-4b3d-b492-c6abca142178"},{"name":"I Believe in You","artist":"Kylie Minogue","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Kylie+Minogue/_/I+Believe+in+You","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"133526","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/fe10877362b6b70e7bb26aacb53395cb.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/fe10877362b6b70e7bb26aacb53395cb.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/fe10877362b6b70e7bb26aacb53395cb.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/fe10877362b6b70e7bb26aacb53395cb.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"80bdc84b-a3fc-43ff-b7b0-73792ff55c33"},{"name":"Believe Me","artist":"Ellie Goulding","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Ellie+Goulding/_/Believe+Me","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"72099","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/73c7bcd8afc3a8fced8204e57add1237.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/73c7bcd8afc3a8fced8204e57add1237.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/73c7bcd8afc3a8fced8204e57add1237.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/73c7bcd8afc3a8fced8204e57add1237.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"739edc9d-81fc-4cd4-b956-10fb6b3a23b1"},{"name":"Believe It or Not","artist":"Nickelback","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Nickelback/_/Believe+It+or+Not","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"134788","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/075d13817b254cc7aa65781ab0b684d8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/075d13817b254cc7aa65781ab0b684d8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/075d13817b254cc7aa65781ab0b684d8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/075d13817b254cc7aa65781ab0b684d8.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"a72860a9-3053-4ca9-bb75-a9ac5e7aa3e7"},{"name":"You Still Believe in Me","artist":"The Beach Boys","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Beach+Boys/_/You+Still+Believe+in+Me","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"220608","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/31990768cf1841418ac79734f985aad4.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/31990768cf1841418ac79734f985aad4.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/31990768cf1841418ac79734f985aad4.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/31990768cf1841418ac79734f985aad4.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"6e930ce8-5166-479d-b130-94ad2a3657f5"},{"name":"I Don't Believe You","artist":"P!nk","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/P%21nk/_/I+Don%27t+Believe+You","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"228386","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/750b6699c39130ca297a1b926db499fa.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/750b6699c39130ca297a1b926db499fa.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/750b6699c39130ca297a1b926db499fa.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/750b6699c39130ca297a1b926db499fa.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"7c4ad927-9f9b-4ffb-85d9-a32f28d8e65d"},{"name":"Believer","artist":"Goldfrapp","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Goldfrapp/_/Believer","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"106440","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/256b872b24ae55669087b359f21c228e.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/256b872b24ae55669087b359f21c228e.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/256b872b24ae55669087b359f21c228e.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/256b872b24ae55669087b359f21c228e.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"859ad1ac-1490-4afc-992b-a050275698c9"},{"name":"Believe","artist":"Skillet","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Skillet/_/Believe","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"66024","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/fd150a61045b2e8216b62be12c7a24a1.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/fd150a61045b2e8216b62be12c7a24a1.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/fd150a61045b2e8216b62be12c7a24a1.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/fd150a61045b2e8216b62be12c7a24a1.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"552626ab-0263-4c4d-a7e0-01fba188977b"},{"name":"Believe Me I'm Lying","artist":"Forever the Sickest Kids","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Forever+the+Sickest+Kids/_/Believe+Me+I%27m+Lying","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"101798","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/fe00b7ed04094e38aa75088431be2b72.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/fe00b7ed04094e38aa75088431be2b72.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/fe00b7ed04094e38aa75088431be2b72.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/fe00b7ed04094e38aa75088431be2b72.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"886cb749-5690-4ac4-b04b-2cf56565345c"},{"name":"Believer","artist":"American Authors","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/American+Authors/_/Believer","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"81361","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/b23ccda434f04126b78ad9ffb373d538.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/b23ccda434f04126b78ad9ffb373d538.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/b23ccda434f04126b78ad9ffb373d538.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/b23ccda434f04126b78ad9ffb373d538.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"9bd653bd-8be3-47b5-977e-13805f6f60f3"},{"name":"Believe in What You Want","artist":"Jimmy Eat World","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Jimmy+Eat+World/_/Believe+in+What+You+Want","streamable":"FIXME","listeners":"116860","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/51deed641dbd4386830422044b52efac.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/51deed641dbd4386830422044b52efac.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/51deed641dbd4386830422044b52efac.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/51deed641dbd4386830422044b52efac.png","size":"extralarge"}],"mbid":"3c32bed3-bb4c-4f92-9eb3-4376c04d5195"}]},"@attr":{}}}
```

использовал такую [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/),чтобы сделать по аналогии ,но из-за сложной струтуры json не могу справиться с данной задачей,что будет проще использовать Retrofit2 или Volley и как?

Answer (score 0):

Данную задачу можно решить с помощью любой из этих библиотек или же даже без них. Вопрос в Вашей усидчивости и желанию изучить ту или иную библиотеку ;)
Чтоб Вам было проще просматривать JSON - можете к примеру воспользоваться вот таким вот ресурсом:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

А вот этот ресурс поможет Вам преобразовать JSON в pojo-объекты:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/